# How to show missing dates in case of application of rolling function

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, cumsum, rolling-computation

Suppose I have a data `df` of some insurance policies.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#Example data
d <- as.Date("2020-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
set.seed(50)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                 activation_dt = round(runif(10)*100,0) +d, 
                 expiry_dt = d+round(runif(10)*100,0)+c(rep(180,5), rep(240,5)))

> df
   id activation_dt  expiry_dt
1   1    2020-03-12 2020-08-07
2   2    2020-02-14 2020-07-26
3   3    2020-01-21 2020-09-01
4   4    2020-03-18 2020-07-07
5   5    2020-02-21 2020-07-27
6   6    2020-01-05 2020-11-04
7   7    2020-03-11 2020-11-20
8   8    2020-03-06 2020-10-03
9   9    2020-01-05 2020-09-04
10 10    2020-01-12 2020-09-14
```

I want to see how many policies were active during each month.  That I have done by the following method.

```
# Getting required result

df %>% arrange(activation_dt) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(activation_dt, expiry_dt), 
               names_to = "event",
               values_to = "event_date") %>%
  mutate(dummy = ifelse(event == "activation_dt", 1, -1)) %>%
  mutate(dummy2 = floor_date(event_date, "month")) %>%
  arrange(dummy2) %>% group_by(dummy2) %>%
  summarise(dummy=sum(dummy)) %>%
  mutate(dummy = cumsum(dummy)) %>%
  select(dummy2, dummy)

# A tibble: 8 x 2
  dummy2     dummy
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2020-01-01     4
2 2020-02-01     6
3 2020-03-01    10
4 2020-07-01     7
5 2020-08-01     6
6 2020-09-01     3
7 2020-10-01     2
8 2020-11-01     0
```

Now I am having problem as to how to deal with missing months e.g. April 2020 to June 2020 etc.

Comment: Just to clarify - you mentioned you want to see how many policies were active *on first day of each month* - does that mean, the total number of policies active on March 1st for example, which counts policies that are activated before March 1st? Or does that include any policies that are active any time during the month of March? The result above has a total of 10 for March, but only 6 actually overlap with the first day of March.

Comment: Yes, you caught it right, actually total policies active during whole month are shown as active representatively on first of that month. Actually I will format that field as month later-on.  I am editing my question.

Comment: If I add `%>% mutate(dummy3 = ifelse(is.na(dummy), lag(dummy), dummy))` last, it replaces only 1 `NA`

Comment: I got it `df %>% arrange(activation_dt) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(activation_dt, expiry_dt), 
               names_to = "event",
               values_to = "event_date") %>%
  mutate(count = ifelse(event == "activation_dt", 1, -1)) %>%
  mutate(date_count = floor_date(event_date, "month")) %>%
  arrange(date_count) %>% group_by(date_count) %>%
  summarise(count=sum(count)) %>%
  complete(date_count = seq.Date(min(date_count), max(date_count), by="month")) %>%
  mutate(count = ifelse(is.na(count), 0, count)) %>%
  mutate(count = cumsum(count)) %>%
  select(date_count, count)`

Comment: Can somebody suggest a better method.  Else I will delete the question as per guidelines

Comment: See the `data.table` solution by @Waldi and my alternative `tidyverse` solution. I think these will give you appropriate results (which appear different than with your method as far as I can tell).

Comment: Thanks @Waldi for the soln

Comment: Thanks @Ben for the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.table` solution :

1. generate the months sequence
2. use non equi joins to find policies active every month and count them

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
months <- seq(lubridate::floor_date(mindat,'month'),lubridate::floor_date(max(df$expiry_dt),'month'),by='month')
months <- data.table(months)

df[,c("activation_dt_month","expiry_dt_month"):=.(lubridate::floor_date(activation_dt,'month'),
                                                  lubridate::floor_date(expiry_dt,'month'))]

df[months, .(months),on = .(activation_dt_month<=months,expiry_dt_month>=months)][,.(nb=.N),by=months]

       months nb
 1: 2020-01-01  4
 2: 2020-02-01  6
 3: 2020-03-01 10
 4: 2020-04-01 10
 5: 2020-05-01 10
 6: 2020-06-01 10
 7: 2020-07-01 10
 8: 2020-08-01  7
 9: 2020-09-01  6
10: 2020-10-01  3
11: 2020-11-01  2
```

Comment: df rows 6 & 7 end in november?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative `tidyverse`/`lubridate` solution in case you are interested. The `data.table` version will be faster, but this should give you the correct results with gaps in months.

First use `map2` to create a sequence of months between activation and expiration for each row of data. This will allow you to group by month/year to count number of active policies for each month.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(month = map2(floor_date(activation_dt, "month"),
                      floor_date(expiry_dt, "month"), 
                      seq.Date, 
                      by = "month")) %>%
  unnest(month) %>%
  transmute(month_year = substr(month, 1, 7)) %>%
  group_by(month_year) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

**Output**

```
   month_year count
   <chr>      <int>
 1 2020-01        4
 2 2020-02        6
 3 2020-03       10
 4 2020-04       10
 5 2020-05       10
 6 2020-06       10
 7 2020-07       10
 8 2020-08        7
 9 2020-09        6
10 2020-10        3
11 2020-11        2
```